# Disable blinking cursor after finishing typing?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any way to stop the cursor from blinking after the user has finished typing text into a text field? I have the textfield type set to `TextFieldType.INPUT`

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, remove focus from the input when the user is finished typing.

The **real** question is, "How do I know when a user is "finished" typing? If the input had a maximum length of 5 characters, we could say the user is "finished" after the 5th character is typed and remove focus then. BUT, what if the user entered an incorrect last character and went to press "backspace"? Well, they're s.o.l. because the cursor isn't there anymore.

Your best bet is to create a timer that removes focus from the input after X seconds. Reset and start the timer after each keyUp event in the input. Decide for yourself how many seconds X should be.

Comment: I'm not sure how to assign the timer to a keyUp event in the input. My text field is called `inputText`

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that if the user clicks on any other area of the stage (outside of the textbox) the text cursor disappears?

Comment: You can google as3 timer and addEventListener. Otherwise, in answer to second question, whatever the user is supposed to be able to click on to remove focus will have to have a click event listener or one transparent mc below the input but above everything else that has the click listener.